# Как можно сократить js код

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var doc = document,
  progressbar = doc.getElementsByClassName("progressbar");
htmlwidth = csswidth = jswidth = phpwidth = sqlwidth = 0;
var htmlprogress = setInterval(function() {
  if (htmlwidth < 445) {
    htmlwidth++;
    progressbar[0].style.width = htmlwidth + "px";
  } else {
    clearInterval(htmlprogress);
  }
}, 50);
var cssprogress = setInterval(function() {
  if (csswidth < 425) {
    csswidth++;
    progressbar[1].style.width = csswidth + "px";
  } else {
    clearInterval(cssprogress);
  }
}, 60);
var jsprogress = setInterval(function() {
  if (jswidth < 350) {
    jswidth++;
    progressbar[2].style.width = jswidth + "px";
  } else {
    clearInterval(jsprogress);
  }
}, 70);
var phpprogress = setInterval(function() {
  if (phpwidth < 300) {
    phpwidth++;
    progressbar[3].style.width = phpwidth + "px";
  } else {
    clearInterval(phpprogress);
  }
}, 80);
var sqlprogress = setInterval(function() {
  if (sqlwidth < 250) {
    sqlwidth++;
    progressbar[4].style.width = sqlwidth + "px";
  } else {
    clearInterval(sqlprogress);
  }
}, 90);
```

```css
div.myskill {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

div.html,
div.CSS,
div.JavaScript,
div.PHP,
div.MySQL {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}

div.html>div.htmlheader,
div.cssheader,
div.javascriptheader,
div.phpheader,
div.mysqlheader {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

div.html>div.htmlprogressbar,
div.cssprogressbar,
div.javascriptprogressbar,
div.phpprogressbar,
div.mysqlprogressbar {
  width: 445px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #b0b0b0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

div.progress,
div.progress1,
div.progress2,
div.progress3,
div.progress4 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: #facc62;
}
```

```html
<div class="myskill">
  <div class="html">
    <div class="htmlheader">
      HTML5
    </div>
    <div class="htmlprogressbar">
      <div class="progress progressbar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CSS">
    <div class="cssheader">CSS3</div>
    <div class="cssprogressbar">
      <div class="progress1 progressbar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="JavaScript">
    <div class="javascriptheader">JavaScript</div>
    <div class="javascriptprogressbar">
      <div class="progress2 progressbar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="PHP">
    <div class="phpheader">PHP</div>
    <div class="phpprogressbar">
      <div class="progress3 progressbar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="MySQL">
    <div class="mysqlheader">MySQL</div>
    <div class="mysqlprogressbar">
      <div class="progress4 progressbar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как можно сократить js код слишком большая нагрузка идет от этого участка кода

Comment: А почему ты эти анимации делаешь с помощью JS, если это можно и в css реализовать и без той самой нагрузки лишней?

Comment: Это часть кода должна срабатывать когда пользователь проскролит до определенного места

Comment: Ну, и что тебе мешает это сделать в css...  В место этих всех setInterval добавляй классы, а transition-ом уже делай что хочешь...

Comment: как я не додумался добавлять классы, спасибо за совет)

Comment: всегда пожалуйста...)))